# Number of nodes in a tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose I have a tree $T$, which is rooted in some vertex $v$. Assign a number $k$ to $v$ and let $v$ have $k-1$ children, number them accordingly. Go on recursively, i.e. one of the children with number $j$ again has $j-1$ children.

As a function of $k$, how many vertices does my tree have?

Comment: Let me rephrase you. $f(k)= 1 + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}f(i)$, $ f(0)=0$, find $k$. Am I right?

Comment: [OEIS A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the construction correctly, if $f(k)$ is the number of vertices, then 
$$f(k)=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}f(i)\tag{1}$$

and $f(1)=1$. Calculating a few values suggests that in general $f(k)=2^{k-1}$. Suppose that this holds for some $k$. Then

$$f(k+1)=\sum_{i=1}^kf(i)=f(k)+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}f(i)=f(k)+f(k)=2^k\;,$$

so by induction it is indeed the case that $f(k)=2^{k-1}$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Here’s an easy way to see why this works. Let $T_k$ be the tree with root labelled $k$: to form $T_{k+1}$ from $T_k$, you just relabel the root from $k$ to $k+1$ and attach a copy of $T_k$ to it.